# Silent Print jasper Report

Tags: java, struts

I am going to create a jasper report. It's either in PDFs or HTML. It saves on the server, so I'm putting this PDFs file in an i frame. Then I'm going to print this i frame content. When I try to print it, it shows a print preview in Chrome. So my requirement is to only print the file. I don't want to show print preview(which is a Chrome feature to show print preview). I want to only select the printer and make it print. I mean silently print. I have been stuck for a couple of days. I mean bypass the print preview. Is there any way to solve the issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Chrome in kiosk mode and add a parameter to stop it from showing the print preview dialogue.

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --kiosk-printing
```

This page explains it in an easy way: http://www.sitepoint.com/google-chrome-kiosk-mode/

Comment: Is it possible from java end.I dont want to go for settings manually.

Comment: I'm confident you can forget about that, as it would involve a website being able to control browsers' settings, which would be a severe security issue.  Also, you will never be able to make your website change the printer selection (you mentioned that in your question).

Comment: There are 2 optimal solutions for this problem: 1) creating a desktop application that takes care of all printing 2) get php to print to the printer directly using TCP (after creating a PDF, as PCL and PostScript are close to impossible to generate yourself)

Comment: And you'll need a printer allowing you to send PDFs over TCP (or FTP) that can render and print them... only a few printers can do that... for you to research ;) but it is possible!